# How do you remove tomcat's default favicon?

Tags: tomcat, favicon

Tomcat 6 seems to be providing a default favicon for my webapp - the tomcat logo. I don't have a favicon.ico in my webapp root, nor does my web.xml mention anything about a favicon. I even have a mapping in my web.xml for *.ico that goes to the default servlet, but it is still showing. How can I remove that tomcat favicon?

I know I can specify a favicon in several ways to override this default icon. I'm trying to find out how (if possible) to prevent the default favicon that tomcat adds and thus have no favicon.

Answer (score 14):

Delete or rename tomcat/webapps/ROOT/favicon.ico and Tomcat will look for a favicon.ico in the root of each web app that it serves.  You don't need to put a  into the head section of each page.

Answer (score 8):

1. If `favicon.ico` is changed in `Catalina Home/webapps/ROOT` then all
   web apps will show this image URL to root-apache-tomcat-x.x.xx/webapps/ROOT.
2. To change icon of each application specify following in head section:

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
   ```

Comment: my webapps/ROOT does not have a favicon.ico. i've updated my question with the clarification that i'm not trying to override the favicon.ico, but rather prevent tomcat from supplying its own so that I can have no favicon.ico.

Answer (score 7):

To get no favicon shown, simply specify none. In most cases you must just remove the "favicon.ico" from your tomcat/webapps/ROOT. If simply removing favicon from tomcat/webapps/ROOT doesn't work for you, make sure that:

1. Double check you really have no favicon.ico in ROOT. As default, the ROOT has a favicon.ico. So if you haven't removed it, it's still there.
2. Check that no tag like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />` is in your index-site or in your called site.
3. Favicons are cached by the browser, a simple "reload" does not reload the favion(!). So maybe your application no longer has a favicon, but your browser still shows it from the cache. Make sure that your browser cache is completely cleared. (In Google Chrome clearing "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files" works for me)

In most cases, it's the browser cache... I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah - thanks for pointing out that Favicons are cached by the browser. This was the step I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and I have resolved it with following solution.
I have added ?v=1.1.0 to the favicon line in head section of html.
Whenever there is a change in favicon image I used to modify this parameter e.g. ?v=1.1.0 to ?v=1.1.1

Please see the sample code for more details.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=1.1.1" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```