# trying to remove the favicon of spring boot in spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.2

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to remove the favicon of my spring boot application and this is the content of my spring-boot-starter-parent in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

After research I have tried changing the application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
```

Still tomcat favicon still appears in the header. what could be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove tomcat's default favicon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561112/how-do-you-remove-tomcats-default-favicon)

Comment: You mean you want to replace or override the Spring Boot's default favicon, the Spring leaf?